Redirect to specific url after remote signing Docusign enveloppe
I'm using Docusign.eSign rest API to send envelope.
After signing, i would like signers to be redirected to a specific url
result is a DocuSign Page with invitation to enrol... or to save a copy of agreement... no timer to process redirect url
Is it possible to bypass that DocuSign page ?
I have set Account/Settings/Brands/Destination Url/Signing completed
My envelope definition contains brandId and BrandLock

Yes, you do this by creating a brand, setting the Envelope Complete URL on that brand, and then, don't forget, using this brand when sending the envelope.
So 3 steps:

Create a new brand
Assign URL you to brand
Assign brand to envelope

Step 3 is shown in this code example - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/apply-brand-to-envelope/
A similar URL for declining to sign, you can find the code and more information in https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-sending-signers-to-different-url-if-they-decline-to-sign
Here is C# code to assigning a brand to an envelope:
EnvelopeDefinition env = CreateEnvelope(signerEmail, signerName, brandId, status, docPdf);
        public static EnvelopeDefinition CreateEnvelope(string signerEmail, string signerName, string brandId, string status, string docPdf)
        {
string docPdfBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(docPdf));

// create the envelope definition
EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition();
env.EmailSubject = "Please sign this document set";

// Create document objects, one per document
Document doc = new Document
{
    DocumentBase64 = docPdfBytes,
    Name = "Lorem Ipsum", // can be different from actual file name
    FileExtension = "pdf",
    DocumentId = "1",
};

// The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
env.Documents = new List<Document> { doc };

// create a signer recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email
// We're setting the parameters via the object creation
Signer signer1 = new Signer
{
    Email = signerEmail,
    Name = signerName,
    RecipientId = "1",
    RoutingOrder = "1",
};

// Create signHere fields (also known as tabs) on the documents,
// We're using anchor (autoPlace) positioning
//
// The DocuSign platform searches throughout your envelope's
// documents for matching anchor strings.
SignHere signHere = new SignHere
{
    AnchorString = "/sn1/",
    AnchorUnits = "pixels",
    AnchorYOffset = "10",
    AnchorXOffset = "20",
};

// Tabs are set per recipient / signer
Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs
{
    SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signHere, },
};
signer1.Tabs = signer1Tabs;

// Add the recipients to the envelope object
Recipients recipients = new Recipients
{
    Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1 },
};
env.Recipients = recipients;
env.Status = status;

// Set the brand id.
env.BrandId = brandId;

return env;
        }


You confirm the correct way which I already used, thanks for that. I tried different scenarios but after validating the signature, the signer always gets the docusign page.
